# Entire desktop screenshot on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I searched alot on forums to find command for capturing everything displayed on the desktop (not just the browser window), but found that this is a bug or limitation. The questions I found were of 2 to 3 years old.

So, is this still a bug or we have got some solution now?

I am using this way but it only captures the browser window.

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);


FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\Users\\rabia.asif\\Desktop\\"+time()+".png"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is NOT bug or limitation, it is so by design. Browser knows only what is displayed in its browser window. If you want a screenshot of the whole screen, you need to ask underlying operating system. Which obviously is system-dependent, so browsers (by design) don't do that. And it is not even good idea for browser be able to do anything in operating system: many very creative people would do very creative things with such tool, and results would not be happy. hackers paradise.

Maybe some VNC tools can be automated: they deal with whole screen and are aware of the operating system they run in.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome itself does not support full page screenshots (as you discovered).

Possible solutions:

1. Chrome screenshot extensions like [Full Page Screenshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl) circumvent this restriction by scrolling, and then stitching together a full page screenshot.
2. Some browser automation tools like [iMacros](http://imacros.net) (based on IE) or [Kantu](https://kantu.io) (based on Chromium) have commands to [capture full page screenshots](https://kantu.io/docs#screenshot) automatically.
3. PhantomJS can do so as well: http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Comment: I will definitely look into these possible solutions. Thanks